How to setup Micrsoft Video Process MFT in MF?
I implemented this topology in VC++.when I start the media session, I get the following error : "No suitable transform was found to encode or decode the content."
here is code:
#include <mfapi.h>
#include <mfidl.h>
#include <mfobjects.h>
#include <mftransform.h>
#include <mfreadwrite.h>
#include <mferror.h>
#include <comdef.h>


// Helper function to create a Media Source Node
HRESULT CreateSourceNode(IMFMediaSource* pSource, IMFPresentationDescriptor* pPD, IMFStreamDescriptor* pSD, IMFTopologyNode** ppNode)
{
    IMFTopologyNode* pNode = nullptr;
    HRESULT hr = MFCreateTopologyNode(MF_TOPOLOGY_SOURCESTREAM_NODE, &pNode);
    if(FAILED(hr)) goto done;

    hr = pNode->SetUnknown(MF_TOPONODE_SOURCE, pSource);
    if(FAILED(hr)) goto done;

    hr = pNode->SetUnknown(MF_TOPONODE_PRESENTATION_DESCRIPTOR, pPD);
    if(FAILED(hr)) goto done;

    hr = pNode->SetUnknown(MF_TOPONODE_STREAM_DESCRIPTOR, pSD);
    if(FAILED(hr)) goto done;

    *ppNode = pNode;
done:
    SafeRelease(&pNode);
    return hr;
}
// Create H264 Decoder and Node
HRESULT CreateH264DecoderNode(IMFTopology* pTopology, IMFTopologyNode** ppDecoderNode) {
    IMFTransform* pDecoderMFT = NULL;
    IMFTopologyNode* pDecoderNode = NULL; 
    HRESULT hr = S_OK;

    hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_MSH264DecoderMFT, NULL,
        CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_PPV_ARGS(&pDecoderMFT));
    if(FAILED(hr)) goto done;

    hr = MFCreateTopologyNode(MF_TOPOLOGY_TRANSFORM_NODE, &pDecoderNode);
    if(FAILED(hr)) goto done;

    hr = pDecoderNode->SetObject(pDecoderMFT);
    if(FAILED(hr)) goto done;

    hr = pDecoderNode->SetUINT32(MF_TOPONODE_NOSHUTDOWN_ON_REMOVE, TRUE);
    if(FAILED(hr)) goto done;

    hr = pTopology->AddNode(pDecoderNode);
    if(FAILED(hr)) goto done;


    *ppDecoderNode = pDecoderNode;
    (*ppDecoderNode)->AddRef();


done:
    SafeRelease(&pDecoderNode);
    SafeRelease(&pDecoderMFT);
    return hr;
}
// Create Microsoft Video Process MFT 
HRESULT CreateVideoProcessNode(IMFTopology* pTopology ,IMFTopologyNode** ppVideoProcessNode) {
    IMFTransform* pMFT = NULL;
    IMFVideoProcessorControl* pVideoCtrl = NULL;
    IMFTopologyNode* pMFTNode = NULL;
    HRESULT hr = S_OK;

    hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_VideoProcessorMFT, NULL,
        CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_PPV_ARGS(&pMFT));
    if(FAILED(hr)) goto done;

    hr = pMFT->QueryInterface(IID_PPV_ARGS(&pVideoCtrl));
    if(FAILED(hr)) goto done;

    hr = MFCreateTopologyNode(MF_TOPOLOGY_TRANSFORM_NODE, &pMFTNode);
    if(FAILED(hr)) goto done;

    hr = pMFTNode->SetObject(pMFT);
    if(FAILED(hr)) goto done;

    hr = pMFTNode->SetUINT32(MF_TOPONODE_NOSHUTDOWN_ON_REMOVE, TRUE);
    if(FAILED(hr)) goto done;

    hr = pTopology->AddNode(pMFTNode);
    if(FAILED(hr)) goto done;


    *ppVideoProcessNode = pMFTNode;
    (*ppVideoProcessNode)->AddRef();

done:
    SafeRelease(&pVideoCtrl);
    SafeRelease(&pMFT);
    SafeRelease(&pMFTNode);
    return hr;
}

// Create Output Node
HRESULT CreateOutputNode(IMFTopology* pTopology, IMFActivate* pActivate,     
    DWORD dwId, IMFTopologyNode** ppNode)   
{
    IMFTopologyNode* pNode = NULL;
    HRESULT hr = S_OK;

    // Create the node
    hr = MFCreateTopologyNode(MF_TOPOLOGY_OUTPUT_NODE, &pNode);
    if(FAILED(hr)) goto done;

    // Set the object pointer.
    hr = pNode->SetObject(pActivate);
    if(FAILED(hr)) goto done;

    // Set the stream sink ID attribute.
    hr = pNode->SetUINT32(MF_TOPONODE_STREAMID, dwId);
    if(FAILED(hr)) goto done;

    hr = pNode->SetUINT32(MF_TOPONODE_NOSHUTDOWN_ON_REMOVE, TRUE);
    if(FAILED(hr)) goto done;

    // Add the node to the topology.
    hr = pTopology->AddNode(pNode);
    if(FAILED(hr)) goto done;

    // Return the pointer to the caller.
    *ppNode = pNode;
    (*ppNode)->AddRef();

done:
    SafeRelease(&pNode);
    return hr;
}

// Function to configure and connect the topology nodes
HRESULT ConfigureTopology(IMFTopology* pTopology, IMFMediaSource* pSource, IMFPresentationDescriptor* pPD)
{
    IMFStreamDescriptor* pSD = nullptr;
    IMFTopologyNode* pSourceNode = nullptr;
    IMFTopologyNode* pDecoderNode = nullptr;
    IMFTopologyNode* pVideoProcessNode = nullptr;
    IMFTopologyNode* pOutputNode = nullptr;
    IMFActivate* pActivate = nullptr;

    HRESULT hr = S_OK;

    // Get the stream descriptor
    BOOL fSelected = FALSE;
    hr = pPD->GetStreamDescriptorByIndex(0, &fSelected, &pSD);
    if (FAILED(hr) || !fSelected)
    {
        return hr;
    }

    // Create the source node
    hr = CreateSourceNode(pSource, pPD, pSD, &pSourceNode);
    if(FAILED(hr)) goto done;

    hr = pTopology->AddNode(pSourceNode);
    if(FAILED(hr)) goto done;

    // Create H264 Decoder Node
    hr = CreateH264DecoderNode(pTopology,&pDecoderNode);
    if(FAILED(hr)) goto done;

    hr = pTopology->AddNode(pDecoderNode);
    if(FAILED(hr)) goto done;

    hr = pSourceNode->ConnectOutput(0,pDecoderNode,0);
    if(FAILED(hr)) goto done;

    // Create Microsoft Video ProcessMFT Node
    hr = CreateVideoProcessNode(pTopology,&pVideoProcessNode);
    if(FAILED(hr)) goto done;

    hr = pDecoderNode->ConnectOutput(0,pVideoProcessNode,0);
    if(FAILED(hr)) goto done;

    // Create the Output Node
    hr = CreateOutputNode(pTopology,&pActivate,0,&pOutputNode);
    if(FAILED(hr)) goto done;

    hr = pTopology->AddNode(pOutputNode);
    if(FAILED(hr)) goto done;

    // Connect the Video Process MFT to the Output Node
    hr = pDecoderNode->ConnectOutput(0, pOutputNode, 0);
    if(FAILED(hr)) goto done;
done:

    // Clean up
    SafeRelease(&pSourceNode);
    SafeRelease(&pDecoderNode);
    SafeRelease(&pVideoProcessNode);
    SafeRelease(&pOutputNode);
    SafeRelease(&pActivate);
    SafeRelease(&pSD);

    return hr;
}


I constructed the topology shown in the figure using TopoEdit,I got the same error.
I couldn't find any instructions on how to use the Microsoft Video Process MFT component in the official Microsoft online documentation.


Remove the Microsoft Video Process MFT,other compenents work well.
[
How to setup Microsoft Video Process MFT component?
